# Displaying images with Base64 string causes slow response time

Tags: reactjs, image, base64

I have a JSON `messages` which contains a message and user id. Initially I stored all users, see below the JSON in the localstorage.

Now I iterate over all `messages` and call the `Message` component. This should display the message with the image. In the `Message` component I let the image be displayed by the correct user. The problem is that I have this image only as a `Base64 String` (see the JSON). If I now have 20 messages then it still runs smoothly, but as soon as more and more are added the whole thing starts to hang and it takes a relatively long time until the user can enter an input or the latest messages are displayed. My question is now is there an option to display the images without the speed delays?

How the User Json looks like in the localstorage

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "username":"Max",
      "image":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAo..."
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "username":"Power",
      "image":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0JasdnHJD..."
   },
]
```

MessageSide

```
function MessageSide(props) {

  return (
      <div class="col flex-fill background--chat">
        <div className="content__body">
          <div className="item"  style={loaded? {} : {display: 'none'}}>
            {messages.map((message) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Message
                    message={message.body} 
                    id={message.id}
                    timestamp={message.timestamp}
                    chatid={message.chatid}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div ref={messagesEndRef}/>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
export default MessageSide;
```

Message

```
export const Message = ({ message, timestamp, image, id, chatid, name }) => {
  
    var users = localStorage.getItem(`userList_${chatid}`);
    users = JSON.parse(users);

  const getImageOfUser = () => {
    //console.log(id)
    //console.log(chatid)

    
    image = users.find((user) => user.id === id).image;
    //console.log(certainUser)
    //console.log(image)
  };
 
  getImageOfUser(); // that is the problem

  return (
    <div className={checkMessageStyle} style={{ animationDelay: `0.1s` }}>
      <div className="chat__item__content">
        <span>{name}</span>
        <div className="chat__msg">{message}</div>
        <div className="chat__meta">
          <span>{timestamp}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Avatar image={image} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Avatar

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Avatar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="avatar">
        <div className="avatar-img">
          <img src={this.props.image} alt="#" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```